# Javascript string to special array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a string:

`var string = "test,test2";`

That I turn into an array:

`var array = string.split(",");`

Then I wrap that array into a larger array:

`var paragraphs =  [array];`

Which outputs:

`[['test','test2']]`

But I need it to output:

`[['test'],['test2']]`

Any clue how I can do this?

Comment: Iterate `array` and push them into `paragraphs` as `.push([arrayItem])`

Comment: why... that doesn't make sense. Why would you have arrays that only have one index ever? wouldn't `['test','test2']` make more sense?

Comment: I would have done what @SterlingArcher had done here, but nem035's solution is more professional!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just map each item into an array containing that item:

```js
var string = "test,test2";
var result = string.split(",").map(x => [x]);
                           // ^--------------
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This did it! Thanks!!

Comment: @ChrisOlson, please accept the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let test_string = "test,test2";

let result = test_string.split(',').map(item => [item])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get expected result using array Concatenation.

```
var string = "test,test2";
var array = string.split(",");
var finalArray=[[array[0]]].concat([[array[1]]])
console.log(JSON.stringify(finalArray));
```

Answer (score -1):

What version of JavaScript are you targeting?

This might be a general answer:

```
var arr = "test,test2".split(",");
var i = arr.length;
while(i--)
    arr[i] = [arr[i]];
```